# using request module inside for each loop node js doesn't update my JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

What could be wrong in this code? I'm not able to get the updated json (variable **updatedDataJSON**) output after the forEach loop, can anyone please help me out? Thanks in advance, here is my code, am I missing something here?

```
app.get('/getDifferences', (req, res) => {
    let changed = false,
        updatedJSON = { data: [] },
        updatedDataJSON = { "url": "", "dta": "", "status": "unchanged" };
    fs.readFile('output.json', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        storedData = data && JSON.parse(data);
        if (storedData) {
            storedData.data.forEach((e) => {
                request.get(e.url).on('res', (html) => {
                    updatedDataJSON.url = e.url;
                    updatedDataJSON.dta = e.dta;

                    if (e.dta && (e.dta.match(/<body[^>]*>[\s\S]*<\/body>/gi)[0] !== html.match(/<body[^>]*>[\s\S]*<\/body>/gi)[0])) {
                        changed = true;
                        updatedDataJSON.status = "changed";
                        updatedDataJSON.dta = html;
                    }
                    updatedJSON.data.push(updatedDataJSON);
                });
            });
            console.log(updatedDataJSON);
        }
    });
    res.end(JSON.stringify(updatedJSON))
});
```

Comment: it would appear that the return of the http request isnt valid or doesnt contain data

Comment: Your console.log statement is firing before the loop has ended. Javascript is synchronous in execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem**

The order that he code will execute is not in the same order you write it. This is called async. Meaning the request.get gets fired away and then later resolved.

You are hoping for this.

1. Read file.
2. Go through first item.
3. Request data for the first item (it fires away)
4. Recieve data for first item (it resolves)
5. Go through the second item.
6. Request data for the second item (it fires away)
7. Recieve data for second item. (it resolves)

What is happening is more like this:

1. Read file.
2. Go through first item.
3. Request data for the first item (it fires away)
4. Go through the second item.
5. Recieve data for FIRST item (it resolves)
6. Request data for the second item (it fires away)

See how the order is different? Your code goes to the second item before it recieves the data from the first. This is because you're asking a webserver for some data. Meanwhile your code keeps on running and then the webservers says "hey here's the data you asked for".

Imagine setting the table and you're putting the forks on the table and ask me to bring the knives. Do put one fork, wait for me to bring one knife. You put another fork, wait for me to bring a knife, etc.

OR

Do you ask me for the knives and meanwhile put all the forks on the table and don't wait for me. When I arrive with the knives you put them on the table.

**The solution**
1) Check out async/await:
https://tutorialzine.com/2017/07/javascript-async-await-explained

OR

2)  Reduce the promise: https://gist.github.com/anvk/5602ec398e4fdc521e2bf9940fd90f84

**In addition**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score 1):

Node js is async. So you have to end the response in callBack of get request within forEach loop when get request will be called storedData.data length time.

Here I attach the code to demonstrate this.

```
    app.get('/getDifferences', (req, res) => {
    let changed = false,
        updatedJSON = { data: [] },
        updatedDataJSON = { "url": "", "dta": "", "status": "unchanged" };
    fs.readFile('output.json', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        var count = 0,
            arraylength;
        storedData = data && JSON.parse(data);
        if (storedData) {
            arraylength = storedData.data;
            storedData.data.forEach((e) => {
                request.get(e.url).on('res', (html) => {
                    updatedDataJSON.url = e.url;
                    updatedDataJSON.dta = e.dta;

                    if (e.dta && (e.dta.match(/<body[^>]*>[\s\S]*<\/body>/gi)[0] !== html.match(/<body[^>]*>[\s\S]*<\/body>/gi)[0])) {
                        changed = true;
                        updatedDataJSON.status = "changed";
                        updatedDataJSON.dta = html;
                    }
                    updatedJSON.data.push(updatedDataJSON);
                    count++;
                    if (count === arraylength) {
                        console.log(updatedDataJSON);
                        res.end(JSON.stringify(updatedJSON));
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is async, It returns a response before reading the file. try [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module or promise to handle async operation.